# File match exclude pattern working in Copy Files task but not in Delete Files task?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

As part of my TFS 2018 build, I want to move files using the Copy Files and Delete Files tasks together. I am using the same file match patterns in both of these tasks, but I seem to be getting different behavior.

**Scenario:** My TFS build copies build artifacts to a network folder `\\some\path\Beta`. In my build, this path is saved as a variable, `$(NetworkPath)`. The root folder of these artifacts is a version number that is, of course, changing on each build. I want to clean this folder up by adding `$(NetworkPath)\PreviousVersions` that holds all previous versions, so that the only version shown in "Beta" is the most recent build.

**My Attempt:** I've added a Copy Files task (first) and a Delete Files task (second) to my build. My idea is to copy everything in `$(NetworkPath)` into `$(NetworkPath)\PreviousVersions` (excluding the contents of `$(NetworkPath)\PreviousVersions`), before I do the second copy to put the new version into `$(NetworkPath)`.

In the task definitions, the Source Folder of both tasks is `$(NetworkPath)`, and the [file matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=vsts) I've defined in the Contents field for both tasks are:

```
**\**
!PreviousVersions\**
```

The Target Folder in the Copy Files task is, naturally, `$(NetworkFolder)\PreviousVersion`.

**Results:** With these search paths, the Copy Files task works properly -- it copies everything that is in `$(NetworkPath)` but is not in `$(NetworkPath)\PreviousVersions` and puts it in `$(NetworkPath)\PreviousVersions`. The subsequent Delete Files task, though, deletes everything from `$(NetworkPath)`, including the entire `$(NetworkPath)\PreviousVersions` folder. I expected it to only delete the files and folders in `$(NetworkPath)` but not in `$(NetworkPath)\PreviousVersions`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should be using Publish Artifacts for this, not Copy Files. Let the builds be responsible for publishing and maintaining available versions, not file shares.

Comment: The negation should be fine but is ignored. There is already an issue and a related PullRequest for the task in question -> https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4936 . Since it doesn't look it has prio or is updated by microsoft i'd suggest you replace 'DeleteFiles' with powershell-task and do the deleting with powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the workaround file matching patterns I found to achieve the behavior I wanted:

1. For the Copy Files task: `*.*.*.*\**`
2. For the Delete Files task: `*.*.*.*`

Clearly, this exploits the fact that the files I wanted to move have a root folder which has a version number as its name (i.e. 2.5.0.11), so this solution is not applicable to many people.

That said, here are some things that helped me narrow down my issue and solution:

- [globtester](https://globster.xyz/) is a handy little minimatch pattern tester.
- When dealing with these two tasks, setting `debug` = `true` in the queuing panel of the build will give you more useful logs on what the match patterns are actually doing.

For most scenarios, Daniel Mann's comment above is applicable, and I will be discussing such a change in the future.